# Impossible type switch case

Tags: go

This program does not compile:

```
package main

type Validator struct {
}

// Error implements error interface
func (v *Validator) Error() string {
    return ""
}

func test() error {
    return &Validator{}
}

func main() {
    switch test().(type) {
    case nil:
        println("No error")
    case Validator:
        println("Validation error")
        return
    default:
        println("Unknown error")
        return
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
prog.go:19: impossible type switch case: test() (type error) cannot have dynamic type Validator (missing Error method)
```

But `Validator` struct has method `Error`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have two different types, `Validator` and the pointer type `*Validator`, and these two types have different method sets.

You have only defined an `Error()` method for the pointer while `Validator` doesn't have this method.

What you can do is the following change:

```
// Error implements error interface
func (v Validator) Error() string {
    return ""
}
```

...

```
case *Validator, Validator: // You are actually getting a *Validator
```

This implements `Error()` for both `Validator` and `*Validator`. As the **[Go specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets)** says:

> The method set of any other type T consists of all methods declared with receiver type T.
>   The method set of the corresponding pointer type *T is the set of all methods declared with
>   receiver *T or T (that is, it also contains the method set of T)

Comment: Do you have any advice on when to define a method on a pointer to object or the object itself?

Comment: Define the method on a pointer when 1. you need to modify the object. 2. it's a big object and copying it is expensive.

Comment: In this case Validator has a size of 0, so it's clearly better to use it than a pointer.

Answer (score 8):

The compiler is correct. `Validator` type does not implement `Error`, `*Validator` does. `Validator` and `*Validator` are different types. Just replace the former with the latter in the type switch:

```
switch test().(type) {
case nil:
    println("No error")
case *Validator:
    println("Validation error")
    return
default:
    println("Unknown error")
    return
}
```

Working example on the Go Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/aWqzPXweiA